# Why does "expr $n - 1" work, but "expr $n -1" doesn't?

Tags: linux, bash

I' have one small problem.
If you want to test here's both bash scripts.
This one is work

```
#!/bin/bash
N=40
while [ "$N" -gt 0 ]
do
echo $N
N=`expr $N - 1`
done
```

This one does not work

```
#!/bin/bash
N=40
while [ "$N" -gt 0 ]
do
echo $N
N=`expr $N -1`
done
```

Look's like problem is on this line N=`expr $N -1`

My system is CentOS 7

bash, version 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Comment: What do you mean the second one doesn't work? What about it isn't working? If those are actually identical then if one works they must both work. Are you sure they are identical? What does `diff` say about them?

Answer (score 5):

`- 1` is two words. `-1` is one word. `$N - 1` is an expression. `$N -1` is two terms with no predicate.

You know what to do, right?

Comment: Is this answer a question? ;-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell Is the "Socratic Method" or at least "Little Schemer" tag already on meta.?

Comment: Thank you kojiro you was right, i must look better next time, sorry for wasting your time.